# Error with plt.savefig in the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

At first, I have to say that I'm a true beginner in Python (and in programming itself) so this may be a silly question but I couldn't find a solution.

I load data from 3 different .csv files then make some calculations and in the end i want to save 3 heatmaps. My problem is with saving. When i use `plt.savefig('whatever.jpg')` it obviously saves only last heatmap in the loop. I tried to change it to `plt.savefig('{}.jpg'.format(i))` but I got an error and I don't know how to fix. I'll appreciate any hints! (Python 3 from Anaconda)

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

instrumenty = ['gold','sp500','dax']

for i in instrumenty:

    i = pd.read_csv(i+'_m.csv', sep=',')
    i['Miesiąc'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(i['Data']).month
    i['Rok'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(i['Data']).year
    i['Zmiana']=i['Zamkniecie'].pct_change()
    i_pt = i[1:].pivot_table(index='Rok',columns='Miesiąc',values='Zmiana')
    sns.heatmap(i_pt, linewidths=1, cmap='PiYG')
    plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(i))
    plt.clf()
```

And the error:

```
   FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5729b6a0480f> in <module>()
     14     i_pt = i[1:].pivot_table(index='Rok',columns='Miesiąc',values='Zmiana')
     15     sns.heatmap(i_pt, linewidths=1, cmap='PiYG')
---> 16     plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(i))
     17     plt.clf()
     18 

C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    694 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
    695     fig = gcf()
--> 696     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    697     fig.canvas.draw_idle()   # need this if 'transparent=True' to reset colors
    698     return res

C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in savefig(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1561             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   1562 
-> 1563         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
   1564 
   1565         if frameon:

C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2230                 orientation=orientation,
   2231                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2232                 **kwargs)
   2233         finally:
   2234             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    530         renderer.dpi = self.figure.dpi
    531         if is_string_like(filename_or_obj):
--> 532             filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb')
    533             close = True
    534         else:
```

Even without plt.savefig i am doing something wrong because the result is [one strange chart with 3 legends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jbsa.jpg) instead of 3 charts.

Comment: Try adding `plt.close()` after `plt.savefig(...)`.  Also, I think the default format output for matplotlib figures is `png`, but someone could correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please reduce this to a minimal working example, consider just making a simple plot and trying to use `savefig` once, showing the associated output and error message. Also specify which version of python you are using (Python 3 from Anaconda?).

Comment: @tmwilson26 Unfortunately i't didn't help.

Comment: It does actually save the plots when you give it a static name though (although overwritten)?  File not found is something I haven't seen when doing matplotlib plots, because it should create the file.

Comment: @oliversm i make it much more simpler and now it looks like there is also a problem with plotting the charts. I have to make some mistake in the loop but i can't see it. (It's Python 3 from Anaconda, i'm using jupyter notebook)

Comment: @tmwilson26 At first, i have changed the code above to make it simpler but still the problem remains. When i use static name it saves chart as attached in the main post.

Comment: Try the answer below, I missed what he pointed out, but that looks like what the problem was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You override `i` here:

```
instrumenty = ['gold','sp500','dax']
for i in instrumenty:
    i = pd.read_csv(i+'_m.csv', sep=',')
```

Better use `name`:

```
for name in instrumenty:
    # use `name`
    i = pd.read_csv(name +'_m.csv', sep=',')
    i['Miesiąc'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(i['Data']).month
    i['Rok'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(i['Data']).year
    i['Zmiana']=i['Zamkniecie'].pct_change()
    i_pt = i[1:].pivot_table(index='Rok',columns='Miesiąc',values='Zmiana')
    sns.heatmap(i_pt, linewidths=1, cmap='PiYG')
    plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(name))
    plt.clf()
```

This is the important part:

```
plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(name))
plt.clf()
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me also, however notably, the `plt.clf()` was the most important, as it solves this problem that @overb had:

"... one strange chart with 3 legends instead of 3 charts."

Comment: Agreed. This line is also important. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the main problem was that I forgot to put the extension `.png` of the file.

After defining:

```
plot_filename = 'plot_'+filename
```

The following **did not work**:

```
plt.savefig(str(plot_filename))
# or this neither
plt.savefig(plot_filename))
```

but the following **did work**:

```
plt.savefig("{}.png".format(plot_filename))
```